# What are the rules for posting an image with my attempts to solve my question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, asking-questions, images

Hi guys not sure if this is the right place to post this but just wondering what is the rules regarding posting images of individual attempts for a question you have asked, i.e. if I have a question, can I show my attempt at the question or understanding of it by uploading a image that is clear?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Ideally you will begin learning how to use MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to post mathematical notation -- [see this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Often beginners learn by getting help from the Community in converting images or "ASCII math" to an elegant math format.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231613/259305

Answer (score 5):

Most important thing is to use MathJax whenever possible. People will invest their time in order to answer your question, so please invest your time in order to ask it properly: Typesetting formulae in MathJax is one aspect of this.

Images should be used to depict an "actual image" like for example the physical setup of an experiment. They should not be used for formulae.

Also note that it is a good idea to only use the Math SE internal uploading feature as opposed to linking external sources. I don't think there is a rule prohibiting external links, but as those links will be broken when an external image gets deleted, the use of external hosts somehow goes against the SE spirit:

Questions should be of value to future visitors and if your question can no longer be understood because an external image source is now missing, that value has been lost.

Answer (score 4):

The better place for questions like this is [Math.Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/). However, I'll answer it here.

You can upload pictures to your question, and that is perfectly acceptable, but I would always recommend writing out any workings you've done using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) - sometimes handwriting (like mine) can be hard to read and the use of Mathjax eliminates that issue. For diagrams or drawings, using images is a good idea however. You can upload them by clicking the icon shown in the picture below, when you go to ask your question. [image]

As hardmath kindly pointed out, you can only upload images if you have $10$ reputation points. Link [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20480/a-bevy-of-questions-with-embedded-images/20730#20730) showing that.

Comment: Many thanks. Added to the post

Comment: A quibble about uploading images.  New users are allowed to do this.  However they can only submit a post with a link to the image, not with the appropriately decorated link that makes the image visible.  It will frequently happen that a persistent new user figures out how to upload the image, but must wait for a kindly Community member (with 10 reputation points) to make the image visible.

Comment: I might add that uploading a picture of math isn't ideal - it's not searchable, it isn't as flexible for rendering on different devices (and not good at all for screen readers), and it's usually less legible than typeset stuff. That said, especially for new users, if someone uploads an image, someone who knows MathJax will probably replace the image by its contents.